# How to fix Accessibility Error - Ensure markup documents contain well-formed elements for input element

Tags: html, tags, accessibility

I'm testing accessibility on my project, and am receiving the error that "Ensure markup documents contain well-formed elements" relating to this bit of code:

[image]

I am not able to figure out what the problem is here.

Any help in figuring out why this doesn't pass the accessibility test would be great.

Tool Used: https://www.webaccessibility.com

Comment: Can you please post actual code or error messages in text instead of  a screenshot ? This is a major accessibility problem for screen reader users, but also improve the chances for those who have the same problem to find this question with search engines in the future. Don't worry for this post, but think about it next time. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do your inputs have labels? They should! Then link them by using an id on the input that is the same as the for on the label. I highly recommend SiteImprove chrome plugin for testing, it gives more specific results and combined with the inspector shows you where each error is in the browser/DOM.

Comment: Actual Code:

`<form action="/searchresults" method="get">
<label for="searchText">Search all jobs by title or education</label>
<input type="text" id="searchText" autocomplete="off" class="searchText2" name="searchText" value="${fn:replace(searchText, '-', ' ')}" placeholder="Search all jobs by title, education" />
<input id="searchSubmit" type="submit" value="Search" />
<div class="seach-suggestions"></div>
</form>`

"SearchText" is dynamic value coming from Backend.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that this is a problem with their parsing engine expecting inputs to have a closing forward slash. (see possible cause 2 though)

### Possible cause 1

Without seeing your original markup it is difficult to say as the error message is not very descriptive. However i do have an educated guess!

You see some people still believe that HTML elements that are self-closing / void elements should have a closing forward slash.

However this has **never** been needed in HTML and has never been in the HTML spec.

Where this comes from is when we thought XHTML was going to be the next big thing (and then HTML 5 came along). I mean it is over 10 years now but we still see it everywhere!

For clarity I think they expect to see:

```html
<input />
```

Where you are (correctly) using:

```html
<input >
```

So from what I can see everything looks fine and you can ignore their error message.

**One easy way to check if this is the case is to add the closing forward slash and see if the error goes away. If it does then you know you can ignore it!**

If the problem still persists then drop a link to the page / put the raw HTML in your question and I will help you see if it is something else.

### Possible cause 2

The only other thing is just check you are using the correct doctype declaration (the first line of your HTML document):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

If you are using something else like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Then the error is your side and you simply need to change that declaration to the first one as otherwise their parsing engine is correct and you **should** be using a closing forward slash as it is required in the XHTML spec!

Comment: Thanks Graham for the revert. 
I have tried first solution but that did not fixed the issue. And I have noticed that after adding < /> in my input field and code deployment, that changes got reverted some how may be due to DOCTYPE.
I want to share my jsp file top 4 lines to give you more info:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix = "fn" %>
<html lang="en-US">`

Do let me know for any change

Comment: Can you please post actual code or error messages in text instead of  a screenshot ? This is a major accessibility problem for screen reader users, but also improve the chances for those who have the same problem to find this question with search engines in the future. Don't worry for this post, but think about it next time. Thank you very much.